# Disable font ligatures in pluma text editor or for the whole system

Tags: fonts, mate-desktop

I have built a debian Bullseye live-dvd using live-config and live-build. The live-dvd has the MATE desktop environment and pluma text editor.

The problem is that pluma is doing font ligatures when I run the live-dvd. The font name is "monospace".

I tryed to add the following text to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf`:

```xml
<match target="font">
  <edit name="fontfeatures" mode="append">
    <string>liga off</string>
      <string>dlig off</string>
   </edit>
</match>
```

But it didn't work.

I think there is a way to disable ligatures because in the system I have installed from the live-dvd I downloaded on debian website, the ligatures are disabled in pluma text editor. But I didn't find anything related to ligatures in the `/etc/fonts` directory.

Is there a way to disable font ligatures in pluma ? Or maybe for the whole system if pluma is using system-wide configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

With the command `fc-match monospace`, I found the two systems wasn't using the same font for monospace. The system which was doing font ligatures was using "Nimbus", and the other "DejaVu".

So I installed the package "fonts-dejavu" on my live-dvd and rebuilt it.

Now pluma is working without font ligature.